# Ruby openssl documentation

Tags: ruby, encryption, documentation, openssl

Is there any online documentation of Ruby's `openssl` library? All I can find are blog posts and third-party articles, and the rdoc itself doesn't really explain how to use the library step-by-step.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some brave soul finally documented it in the latest versions of ruby.  See github:

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/openssl/ossl.c#L409

**EDIT**: just to give credit where it's due, the commit history says that Eric Hodel is responsible for this good documentation.

Answer (score 2):

This can only be a partial answer since I'm also looking to Ruby to use commercial grade HTTPS functionality.  As background, I was tech-support engineer for EFT*POS and SmartCards some long time ago and an internal *ad hoc* reviewer for draft the CCITT X.600 standards.  Fortunately, my area was secure-messaging and services (like API-s).

And while that was in another life ... I still remember things.  I don't especially think it is the OpenSSL implementers' job to explain how-to-use an [OpenSSL interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openssl).  At the same time, I believe I appreciate the frustration of '*starting*' with any of *this stuff*.

And ... I definitely think it is important for *published* libraries, modules, gems, components and bits to be documented *by humans*.  I only find RDoc and similar 'generated' documentation useful in a limited set of development or bug fix use cases.  For example a library like OpenSSL '*might*' point to [SSL and TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) overviews and 'why' examples.  I think it is vital that library and gem implementers *engage with* the idea that you are writing something that others will use *to **effect***.

- Example: a hammer is used to effect to bang a nail and join two pieces of wood.
- That same hammer can also be used to impact the shell-casing of a bullet and cause serious outcomes.
  I prefer that Ruby Open SSL documetation begin with the *meaning* and *impact* of the tool, component or module.  A good place to gain some background is with this post:
- **[How to Cure Net::HTTP’s Risky Default HTTPS Behavior](http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to-cure-nethttps-risky-default-https-behavior-4010.html)**, Peter Cooper (*09-Oct-2010*).
  Also, see:
- **[Always Verify SSL Certificates](https://github.com/jamesgolick/always_verify_ssl_certificates)**,
  And follow the steps shown for [cURL command line](http://curl.haxx.se) so you will have a check for your machine's connection and the encoding.
- http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Earlier I tried pointing my Ruby test script to the CA-bundle cURL command line uses.  That didn't work, whereas if I test without SSL verification and if I use cURL with SSL on the command line, life it good (*again*).

If that gets you started, let me know what the next step is.  Sometimes the lack of documentation is because there is a *work in progress* and other times it is because good-looking, robust bits like OpenSSL just work.  In this case '***we***' (collectively) want to know how to apply best-practice in particular situations.

Join in encouraging (rewarding) people to  *engage with* the idea or documenting things for others to be able and motivated to: use *to **effect***.